# How to create 2 columns as positions in the Home page?

Tags: joomla-2.5, templates, positions

I have made my school's Website, which needs to update every single day some news or events.

So I decided to divide the Home page in 2 columns: News & Events.

These 2 columns should be 2 positions x & y; they should show just the articles which have been told to display in that position,
OR
each position should show all the articles of a specified category.

Anyway, my biggest problem isn't to assign a category to an article or to give a position to this one; but my real problem is:

**How do I create a position of the exactsize I want and to 'position' it (sorry for this word-joke) in the exact place I wish it to appear?**

I already know I need to modify a file via FTP to create a new position, but how do I 'customize it' in this way? In addition I'd like to make them appear just for a limited time, after that they all will be displayed in a general article in another menu voice.

I am leaving you my Website [page](http://www.liceocroceroma.it/). I really know you'd need maybe my template file? If so please do not rate this post yet but ask me for the exact file you wish to have before helping here, thanks!

**Consider that right now we have 2 columns but they're not 2 positions but 2 articles side by side which is horrible and not dynamic!**

Comment: Based on your question, is sounds like you are having issues with how your multi-column layout, but upon reviewing your site the columns seem to be properly positioned.  Is the issue about layout/design or how to get two unique article category streams side by side using Joomla core extensions?

Comment: Look, what you see on my school's website.. are 2 articles side by side and not 2 positions! Those articles are in the 'main' position not in the 'x' and 'y' positions @BrianBolli

Comment: I checked your site and wasn't able to see what you are describing. What is exactly the question here? How to make 2 elements have the same size?

Comment: By position I mean just like the banner position, the bottom position etc.. Where you can position elements, not the elements their self. So how to customize the size and the location of a position? (On my question I ask for 2 positions side by side) @FFrewin

Answer (score 1):

Your initial question is yet a bit confusing to me. I am grabbing the opportunity, based on your last comment (), to explain briefly a couple things:

**Your last comment:**

> By position I mean just like the banner position, the bottom position
>   etc.. Where you can position elements, not the elements their self. So
>   how to customize the size and the location of a position? (On my
>   question I ask for 2 positions side by side)

- The positions you mentioned, are module positions specified by the template.
- Modules are small pieces of software (simple extensions) that can print out site content, according to how they are designed.
- Template is responsible for the output and the layout of the content.
- The output of the template is an html document. The standard of positioning elements inside an html document is with CSS.

Maybe in your case, all you want to do is to find a module suitable to select and display the specific content you want. Then find if your template provides a module position that can display 2 or more modules aligned -one next to each other-, and add 2 instances of that module -1 for each of the side-side blocks- in this position.

You could ask the template provider if there is a such module position.
If it's a custom template, then you could create one, module position and add the appropriate css to make the content inside.

How the modules will be positioned side by side is a pure css thing.
Usually you need to float the elements to the left or right, and give them a total width, including margins, borders etc of 100%. (It can be a 50%-50% for each of the 2 modules).

If the above sound like Chinese, then another suggestion is to search if there are any modules that are designed to display the content the way you want (in grid view). In this case, you could just use 1 module and configure it to show the content you want in 2 columns. Check in Joomla Extensions Directory - I believe there should be something to fit your requirements.

**Update - Check this similar question here:**   [Placing two modules side by side](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/9845/placing-two-modules-side-by-side/9847#9847)

Comment: Nah it's completely understandable, my question is (you got it) how to set the CSS of the new position. I know how to create one, but I am not sure how to see it works and it's of the size I have set it on

Comment: @Snip3r_bow:: Ok, so do you have the 2 modules published at the position you want to show them, so we could see them and advise on how to position them?

Comment: Yes I do, but they are 2 articles in a single position

Comment: Automatically posted side by side

Comment: I am not sure we are talking the same language - anyhow - where are these 2 articles. And when you say you know how to create one position you mean, you know how to add a module position in your template?

Comment: This @FFrewin http://yootheme.com/themes/documentation/customizing/create-a-new-module-position

Comment: I just need to know how to make 2 of them side by side with CSS, that's it